# how to move to another activity after clicking logout from facebook logout button in android?

Tags: android, facebook-login

From the login button in my login page activity, I can login to Facebook and then move to Main Activity when successful and I have created a new Login button in main activity. I want that after logout I move back to the login activity so I made a setOnClickListener and an intent but it showing a dialogue box [Dailogue Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM5HH.png) for confirmation and before clicking it, the intent takes me to the login page activity. I want that after confirming the logout in dialogue box I move to Login activity.

My code on Main activity -

```
private void logout() {
    loginButton = new LoginButton(MainActivity.this);
    loginButton.performClick();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginPage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
}
```

My code on LoginPage Activity -

```
AccessTokenTracker tokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
    @Override
    protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
        if (currentAccessToken != null) {
            Intent i2 = new Intent(LoginPage.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i2);
        } else {
            loadUserProfile(currentAccessToken);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you add more info about the logout method? Where and how do you call it? Since it is a dialog, it should be called from the dialog but you said it was in the main activity.

Comment: Facebook SDK provides its own Login button which opens a small browser at the time of login and opens a dialogue box for confirming logout at the time of logout. please check - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/